# How can I execute a long SQLCommand within docker with one command

Tags: sql-server, docker

I've pulled the latest version of a microsoft sql server docker image (*mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest*) and now I want to execute a longer command on this image.

After poking around a bit it seems there is a character limit of ~1000 characters per command.

e.g. the following command can't be executed:

```
docker exec -it sql1 /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "Str@ngPassword1" -Q "SELECT TOP (1000) [name] ,[object_id] ,[principal_id],[schema_id],[parent_object_id],[type],[type_desc],[create_date],[modify_date],[is_ms_shipped],[is_published],[is_schema_published],[is_replicated],[has_replication_filter] ,[has_opaque_metadata],[has_unchecked_assembly_data],[with_check_option] ,[is_date_correlation_view] ,[is_tracked_by_cdc] FROM [master].[sys].[all_views]  where Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%'  and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%'  and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%'  and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%'  and Name like '%a%' and Name like '%a%'"
```

The error is:

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Server 7c30e32209f0, Line 1
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '%a
>   '.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server 7c30e32209f0, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '%a

If you remove one *"and name like '%a%'"* the code executes fine.

Is there a workaround for this constraint?

- My host is Microsoft Windows 10 Version 1803
- Running the latest Docker Desktop Version 2.0.0.3 (31259)

Comment: Why do you repeat the clause `AND name LIKE '%a%'` 32 times in the first place?

Comment: `sqlcmd -i` accepts file input. On Windows it does not accept `-` to read from stdin, don't know if it does on Linux. On Windows it does accept piped output, however. Any of these, possibly combined with a here-string, should do the trick.

Comment: For the 1000 character problem, it seems like problem is with `docker exec` and not `sqlcmd`. I cannot replicate the 1,000 character limit issue on Windows 10 or Ubuntu 16.04. I just ran an almost 3,500 character long with using `-Q` without any problems.

Comment: @Larnu this is an example, i've got another (useful) script but it needs more setup within the docker. I could reduce the problem to this simple but stupid select statement which behaves strange according to the length. 
Jeroen Mostert I'll try using the pipe thanks